# How to find and address performance issues in a mobile platform built using React-Native & Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, react-native

We hired a team overseas to build a social dining and event mobile platform. The platform was built in React & Javascript and was supposed to be designed to be scalable, but I'm noticing that it's slow and unreliable, especially when we have larger number of users. At times is crashes as more features are being accessed. I'm not sure how to identify and address the performance issues. The original team that built it is not being very helpful and I fear they took some shortcuts. I'm hoping to get some advice on where to start and how to find technical help to address the problem. Specifically, I'm wondering:

What tools and techniques can I use to identify the root cause of the performance issues?

Are there any best practices for optimizing the performance of a platform that handles social events and orders?

Looking to possibly hire a technical expert to help identify and fix the issues.  If you specialize in performance optimization and scaling of web applications, please reach out.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

The team that built it is no longer part of the project and we have only one technical person who isn't experienced enough to get to the bottom of the issues

Comment: What do you mean by slow? There are several elements you need to consider but a good starting point is if the UI (the app itself) is slow, or if it is related to network calls (long wait for http requests). If you can identify those first you can take actions. I doubt it is a react native/js problem given that you say you experience this "during peak usage periods". Sounds like a server side problem.

Comment: Is this a web application or a react native mobile application? On the title and tags are different than what you're defining.

Comment: It's a native mobile application.

Comment: It is definitely not a server issue. The issues arise when we have a larger number of users that are using more features.